# functools.partial and how it composes non-keyword arguments

Tags: python, closures, decorator

I've found functools.partial to have a lot of great use cases.

However, I found the need to define what I call partial_right. It's like partial, but binds non-kwargs from the "right".

My question will be... do I need partial_right, or am I missing something? That I can achieve what I want with partial() or some other technique.

functools.partial is implemented something like:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    ...
```

It's the ordering of "(args + fargs)" that is my issue. That ordering is great for some purposes, but I found times where I want the opposite ordering:

```
def partial_right(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        ...
        return func(*(fargs + args), **newkeywords)
    ...
```

One such use case is when code is building 'dynamic' methods through some decorator on the method. The value of 'self' isn't known at this point:

```
 class SomeClass(object):
     @decorator(a_value, b_value)
     def my_method(self, a, b):
         ...
```

In my use case all the parameters for my_method are known, except for 'self'. So partial_right is used to dynamically create what is equivalent to:

```
  def my_method_dynamic(self):
     self.my_method(a_value, b_value)
```

Comment: Great narrative, but what's the question? :)

Comment: :) Am I missing something... can I do what I want without creating partial_right.  I'll update the question to make that clear!

Comment: `functools.partial` can only be used to specify the *leftmost* positional arguments.  So yes, you'll need to do something else if you need to specify ones other than the leftmost args.

Comment: An alternative is to use [default argument values](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) on function parameters. That way, you can use the keyword arguments part of `partial` to pass those arguments in.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific use case, it may be more appropriate to use an [`operator.methodcaller`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
import operator
my_method_dynamic = operator.methodcaller('my_method', a_value, b_value)
my_method_dynamic(obj) # calls obj.my_method(a_value, b_value)
```

Comment: Good to know about methodcaller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to only use kwargs and give them placeholder values.  This way, you'll be able to specify the arguments you need in whatever order you want.

```
def my_method_dynamic(self, a=None, b=None):
  #do some stuff

partial_func = partial( my_method_dynamic, a=200, b=400)
#returns a thunk that still takes the desired argument
```

Comment: You don't need the placeholder values. You can pass `a` and `b` as keyword arguments anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your use case is, but you can also do this, which might even be easier for your use case...

```
class MC2(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.f2 = partial(self.f1, 4, 6)

     def f1(self, a, b):
         print a,b
```

That doesn't work for classes, but `self.f1` appears to be a closure itself, with `self` already bound, so it works for instances. Obviously this doesn't work for decorators either, since they are processed when the class is defined.

Comment: Mine was a very generic question summarizing a broad collection of use cases that I've found. And I gave a very specific / simple example.